# Jackson Exception when parsing Yaml with a Map of List values

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, dropwizard

I have a Yaml document that includes map entries that correspond to lists.  Here's an example:

```
environments:
  qa: [ 'us-east-1' ]
  staging: [ 'us-east-1', 'us-west-2' ]
```

I am using Jackson 2.3.2 to parse the document into a class using the following field & accessors:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> environments = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

@JsonProperty
public Map<String, List<String>> getEnvironments() {
    return environments;
}

@JsonProperty
public void setEnvironments(Map<String, List<String>> environments) {
    this.environments = environments;
}
```

I'm testing the reading of the Yaml file with the following:

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/configuration_test.yml");
config = mapper.readValue(inputStream, MyConfiguration.class);
```

The following exception is thrown with a stacktrace that's not particularly helpful:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type [collection type; class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList, contains [simple type, class io.dropwizard.metrics.ReporterFactory]]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.createCollectionDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:814)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:392)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:350)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:263)
... 42 more
```

Any idea how to get Jackson to parse the Map value as a List?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem extending dropwizard's configuration class. As CAB mentioned, using `Jackson.newObjectMapper` instead of `new ObjectMapper` solved the issue. Now my test looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson.newObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

MyConfiguration myConfig = mapper.readValue(fixture("fixtures/configuration.yml"), MyConfiguration.class);

// Asserts
```

PS: I am using `io.dropwizard.testing.FixtureHelpers.fixture` to fetch the YAML file.

Comment: I'm not able to do the same as newObjectMapper() doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Which dropwizard version are you using?

Comment: Dropwizard version is 0.7.1

Comment: I'm using 0.8, the `Jackson` class is part of dropwizard  `io.dropwizard.jackson`. You can either upgrade your DW version or use  `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to properly configure your ObjectMapper. In dropwizard, there is `Jackson.newObjectMapper()`

Answer (score 2):

This was actually due to my binding class extending from the DropWizard 'Configuration' class.  Parsing the Yaml mentioned in the issue worked fine when using a binding class that did not extended from the DropWizard 'Configuration' class.

It's worth noting that the exception occurred only when run in a JUnit test (TDD, of course), not when running the DropWizard application.  The exception did not occur when the Yaml file was read during normal application startup.